# Order of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, entire-functions

Let $f$ be the a power series over $\mathbb{C}$ of infinite radius. The order $\rho(f)$ of $f$ is defined to be  the infinum of the following set : 
$$ \{ A \ge  0 \mid \exists r_0\ge 0, \forall r\ge r_0, M_f(r) \le \exp(r^A)\}$$
Where $M_f(r)$ is the supremum of $f$ over all complex numbers of norm $r$.

> > How does one show the following identify :
> >      $$ 1/\rho(f) = \lim\inf (- \dfrac{\ln|a_n|}{n\ln n})$$
> >     Where $f(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n$

I managed to show an inequality. 
Let $A > \rho(f)$, then for $r$ big enough, $M_f(r) \le \exp(r^A)$. We then use the identity 
$$2\pi r^n a_n = \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{it}) e^{-int}\mathrm{d}t $$ 
To obtain 
$$  |a_n| \le r^{-n}M(r)$$
For $r$ big enough, we therefore have 
$$ | a_n|\le \exp( r^A - n\ln r)$$
$$ \rightarrow \dfrac{-\ln |a_n|}{n\ln n} \ge \frac{\ln(r)}{\ln n} - \dfrac{r^A}{n\ln n}$$
For $n$ big enough, one can set $r= n^{1/A}$ and use the previous inequality : 
$$ \dfrac{-\ln |a_n|}{n\ln n} \ge  \frac{1}{A} - \frac{1}{\ln n}$$ 
Taking the lower limit, we obtain 
$$\lim\inf (- \dfrac{\ln|a_n|}{n\ln n}) \ge \frac{1}{A}$$
Then, by letting $A\to \rho(f)$ I get 
$$\lim\inf (- \dfrac{\ln|a_n|}{n\ln n}) \ge \dfrac{1}{\rho(f)} $$

I'm having trouble showing the other side now, my idea was to take $A < \lim\inf (- \dfrac{\ln|a_n|}{n\ln n})$, then there exists $n_0\ge 0$ such that $n\ge n_0$ implies 
$$ -\dfrac{\ln |a_n|}{n\ln n} \ge A $$
$$ \rightarrow \ln |a_n| \le - A n\ln n$$
$$  |a_n| r^n \le \exp( n\ln r - A n\ln n)$$
$$ |a_n| r^n \le \left( \frac{r^{1/A}}{n}\right)^{nA} $$
At first sight, this looks good as the right hand side is close to
$$ \dfrac{ r^{n/A}}{n^n} \le \dfrac{r^{n/A}}{n!} $$
And the latter sums to $\exp(r^{1/A})$ and the other inequality follows. But I don't see how I can achieve that inequality. I tried taking $B< A$ but it doesn't  get rid of the exponent over the $n^n$. I also tried splitting the sum in 2 according to $ r^{1/A} /n \le \ge 1$ and use inequality but the splitting depends on $n$. 
So I am stuck, and starting to feel like I should try to pursue another idea, even though this seems to be the "natural" path. But I can't think of anything.

Any ideas to solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a good way, just the final estimate is missing. This is easier to do with the whole series than termwise. Let me however replace your $A$ with $1/\vartheta$ so that at the end I get exponents of $\vartheta$ instead of $1/A$. What we want to show is
$$\frac{1}{\vartheta} < \liminf_{n \to \infty} \biggl(\frac{-\ln \lvert a_n\rvert}{n\ln n}\biggr) \implies \vartheta \geqslant \rho(f)\,.$$
You already found
$$\lvert a_n\rvert < \frac{1}{n^{n/\vartheta}}$$
for $n \geqslant n_0$. Hence there is a $b_1 > 0$ such that
$$\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant b_1\cdot \frac{1}{n^{n/\vartheta}}$$
holds for all $n$. Then we have
$$M(r) \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert r^n \leqslant b_1\cdot \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n^{n/\vartheta}}$$
for all $r \geqslant 0$. For fixed $r > 0$ the expression
$$\frac{r^t}{t^{t/\vartheta}}$$
attains its maximum at $t = r^{\vartheta}/e$, and the maximum is
$$\exp \biggl(\frac{r^{\vartheta}}{e}\log r - \frac{r^{\vartheta}}{e} \log \frac{r}{e^{1/\vartheta}}\biggr) = \exp \biggl(\frac{r^{\vartheta}}{e\vartheta}\biggr)\,.$$
We use this bound for the terms with index $n < (2r)^{\vartheta}$. For $n \geqslant (2r)^{\vartheta}$ we have
$$\biggl(\frac{r}{n^{^/\vartheta}}\biggr)^n \leqslant \frac{1}{2^n}$$
and thus we obtain
\begin{align}
M(r) &\leqslant b_1\cdot\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n^{n/\vartheta}} \\
&\leqslant b_1\biggl(\bigl(1 + (2r)^{\vartheta}\bigr)\exp \biggl(\frac{r^{\vartheta}}{e\vartheta}\biggr) + 2\biggr) \\
&\leqslant 4b_1(2r)^{\vartheta}\exp \biggl(\frac{r^{\vartheta}}{e\vartheta}\biggr)
\end{align}
for $r \geqslant 1/2$. This implies $\vartheta \geqslant \rho(f)$, as needed.

Comment: Very nice thanks a lot ! I need some time to understand how I can think of doing that next time now :)

Comment: Do it like I did: bang your head against the wall for some time (figuratively), then say "Screw it, let's be brutal and see whether that's good enough!" The reason why brutal often works in such situations is that since power series have a fast decaying tail (when convergent), the value can — for positive terms — reasonably be estimated by the relatively few largest terms. Thus a bound for the terms, and a bound for the number of large terms can give a decent bound for the sum of the series.

Comment: Thanks for the tip !

Comment: @DanielFischer: Instructive answer, instructive comment. (+1)