# Bound on integral on function implies bound order of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $\int_{\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|^2e^{-|z|^2} <\infty$ (with Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$). I need to prove that $f(z)$ has order $\le 2$.

My ideas:

1. Try to find bounds on coefficients and derive information about order from this bound.
2. Try to rewrite integral as integral over integrals over circles and with some tricks like moving constant from the right under the integral by using $1 = \int_0^\infty (-a)e^{(-a)|z|}$ and connecting result that some integral is zero with order of function
3. Try to find some information about areas where function is "bad" and if they are not empty find some contradiction.

None of them were successful, so i'm asking for hints/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine idea 1 with the start of idea 2.

On the circle $\lvert z\rvert = r$, writing $z = re^{i\varphi}$ yields
$$\lvert f(z)\rvert^2 = \sum_{m,n = 0}^{\infty} a_n\overline{a_m} r^{n+m} e^{i\varphi(n-m)}\,.$$

Plugging this into the integral and using polar coordinates gives
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{C}} \lvert f(z)\rvert^2 e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2}\,d\lambda
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty} a_n\overline{a_m} r^{n+m} e^{i\varphi(n-m)}\,d\varphi\; e^{-r^2} r\,dr \\
&= \pi \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert^2 r^{2n} e^{-r^2}\: 2r\,dr \\
&= \pi \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert^2 \int_0^{\infty} u^n e^{-u}\,du \\
&= \pi \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\rvert^2 \cdot n!\,.
\end{align}

In particular, $\sqrt{n!}\,\lvert a_n\rvert$ is bounded. From this you can deduce that the order of $f$ is at most $2$ (e.g. using the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527179/order-of-a-power-series)).